# Pandas randomly inserting non-existent delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter

I'm really scratching my head on this one, but it makes no sense to me. I'm using pandas is a very simple way, to read in a tsv. Here is the very minimal code:

```
source = pd.read_csv("neimanmarcus.csv", sep="\t")
images = source["image_link"]
```

All rows in this file have exactly 53 tabs symbols. For some reason, pandas believe that about 2% of them have exactly 72 tab symbols instead. This results in the following errors:

> pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 54 fields in line x, saw 73

That said, upon manual inspection I cannot find any difference in the affected rows. It would be very problematic to skip rows in this situation, so I'm trying to resolve this, but I'm at my wits end. I'm sorry if this is something silly, but here are examples of "correct" and "incorrect" rows.

Correct:

```
sku157001669    Tango Dancer-Print A-Line Dress, Size: 4, TANGO - Carolina Herrera  Carolina Herrera Tango Dancer-Print A-Line Dress Details Carolina Herrera tango dancer-print woven dress. Approx. measurements: 35.5"L center back to hem, 35.5"L center front to hem. V'd jewel neckline. Cap sleeves. Self-tie belt at natural waist; ties at left. Inverted center pleat at A-line skirt. Straight hem. Fit and flare silhouette. Hidden back zip. Cotton/spandex; dry clean. Made in Italy. Model's measurements: Height 5'10"/177cm, bust 34"/86cm, waist 26"/66cm, hips 35.5"/90cm, dress size US 2. Designer About Carolina Herrera: The empress of classically refined looks for both day and evening, Carolina Herrera launched her eponymous line in 1980 after encouragement from her friend, legendary Vogue editor Diana Vreeland. Over the years she has collected a number of fashion's highest accolades as well as a star-studded client list. With both a global focus and adoration for the sum of all things beautiful, Carolina Herrera has been hailed as "Fashion's First Lady." Size: 4. Color: TANGO. Age Group: Adult. Material: 97% COTTON, 3% ELASTANE. Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Dresses  Women's Apparel > Mid-Length > Daytime Dresses > Mid    1390.00 USD 1390.00 USD     http://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-us/Carolina-Herrera-Tango-Dancer-Print-A-Line-Dress/prod177890243/p.prod     http://images.neimanmarcus.com/product_assets/B/2/W/Y/K/NMB2WYK_mz.jpg  http://images.neimanmarcus.com/product_assets/B/2/W/Y/K/NMB2WYK_az.jpg  Carolina Herrera    07667702164817  prod177890243       new in stock        prod177890243   TANGO   97% COTTON, 3% ELASTANE     4           female  Adult       US::Ground:0.00 USD
```

Incorrect:

```
sku158601482    Sleeveless Faux-Wrap Jersey Dress, Women's, Size: 2X, BLACK - Eileen Fisher Eileen Fisher Sleeveless Faux-Wrap Jersey Dress, Women's Details Eileen Fisher jersey dress in your choice of color. Round neckline; sleeveless. Faux-wrap style. Shift silhouette. Viscose/spandex; machine wash. Made in USA of imported materials. Model's measurements: Height 5'10.5"/179cm, bust 32"/81cm, waist 24"/61cm, hips 35.5"/90cm, dress size US 2/4. Necklace not included. Designer Please note: Apparel may be available in more sizes: Shop Eileen Fisher Petite Shop Eileen Fisher Women's About Eileen Fisher: Former interior and graphic designer Eileen Fisher launched her self-named collection in 1984. The acclaimed designer made her mark with clean lines, simple shapes, and a timeless, functional style. Size: 2X. Color: BLACK. Age Group: Adult. Material: " 92% Viscose/8% Spandex F4VF-D3502 / D2502X: Body: 92% Viscose, 8% Spandex Hem: 80% Recycled Polyester, 20% Lycra? F4VF-S1496: Body: 92% Viscose, 8% Spandex Hem Panel: 80% Recycled Polyester, 20% Lycra?. Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Dresses  Women's Apparel > Women's > Special Sizes > Mid 198.00 USD  198.00 USD      http://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-us/Eileen-Fisher-Sleeveless-Faux-Wrap-Jersey-Dress-Women-s/prod179830418/p.prod      http://images.neimanmarcus.com/product_assets/T/A/6/X/8/NMTA6X8_mz.jpg  http://images.neimanmarcus.com/product_assets/T/A/6/X/8/NMTA6X8_az.jpg  Eileen Fisher   00713259663697  prod179830418       new in stock        prod179830418   BLACK   " 92% Viscose/8% Spandex F4VF-D3502 / D2502X: Body: 92% Viscose, 8% Spandex Hem: 80% Recycled Polyester, 20% Lycra? F4VF-S1496: Body: 92% Viscose, 8% Spandex Hem Panel: 80% Recycled Polyester, 20 Graphic 2X          female  Adult       US::Ground:0.00 USD
```

In this situation simply calling `line.split('\t')` works as expected, pandas just seems to break for some reason.

Comment: I can't reproduce it now, but try to put engine='python' in the read_csv()

Comment: Tabs don't seem to paste properly into the StackOverflow editor, so cutting and pasting your sample just gives a string with no tabs at all.  Can you link to an external file somewhere that contains a small sample (e.g., your examples of correct and incorrect rows)?

Comment: @BrenBarn totally happy to, know any easy way to do that? Github gist?

Comment: @Fiabetto already tried, resulted in an even more brittle error.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: Yes, gist, or pastebin, or some such site.

Comment: @BrenBarn Data can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Slater-Victoroff/cff3390e1ac123d3814e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data contains unmatched quote characters (it seems to be using `"` to represent inches in things like `Height 5'10.5"`).  This makes the parser think there are quoted fields, but results in corrupted data because the quotes aren't paired.

Try passing `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` as an additional argument to `read_csv`.  (You'll need to do `import csv` first.  Or you can just pass `quoting=3`.)

Comment: Ah, this is it! Ended up just using the .split('\t') version, but this is super helpful to know. Still confused as to why the number of fields it saw increased instead of decreasing, since quoting in my mind would only decrease the number of fields, but this does in fact fix the problem.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: It may have thought there was a quoted value with a line break inside it, causing two rows to be combined into one (which would then have more tabs).

Comment: Oooh, that makes total sense, so if there are two lines in a row with un-matched quotes this error occurs. Great to know!